# 1 hour skipped when i add seconds manually

Tags: php, time, xampp, mktime

I know it's gonna sound you strange.. but it's happening..

I am trying `mktime()` function to create a seconds string:

```
$time = mktime(21,0,0,3,29,2014);
echo date("d-M, h:i A", $time);
```

And then I add 21600 (6 Hours) seconds in it..

```
 $newstr = $time+21600;
 echo  echo date("d-M, h:i A", $newstr);
```

I Expect this output:

```
29-Mar, 09:03 PM
30-Mar, 03:03 AM
```

But I am getting this:

```
29-Mar, 09:03 PM
30-Mar, 04:03 AM      // It must be 03:03 AM
```

Any one knows what the problem is..? I am using xampp.

Comment: [works for me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OnNwsM). FYI, this is a bad way to do date math. Use DateTime instead.

Comment: @faintsignal Quite Possible.. How to solve it?

Comment: `h:m` do you mean `h:i`? (minutes, not month number)

Comment: @MarkBaker i edited it.. My Problem is other one.. How i can solve this problem man.. i am very worry about it.......Actually Problem is with Hours.

Comment: Actually Problem is with Hours..

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/6RMxrN

Comment: Output both dates with timezone included in the mask to verify whether DST even comes into play or not.

Comment: NOt Sure, but i think  someone deleting comments..

Answer (score 3):

Your timezone is set to a region for which Daylight Savings Time is enacted on March 30, 2014, so the latter date ends up being adjusted to DST and is one hour later than you'd expect mathematically.

http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/europe-starts-dst-2014.html

You can verify this by printing your before and after dates with the timezone marker `e` and DST marker `I` included in `date`'s mask.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add this line before your code

```
ini_set('date.timezone','UTC');
```